# Wifi not working after rooting

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, custom-roms, 7.0-nougat

I have the Samsung galaxy A5 2016 (SM-A510F) and recently upgraded it with the russian nougat firmware (i'm from Europe). Everything worked (even the wifi and mobile data). Later I rooted my phone and put TWRP on my phone (the same zips I've used earlier on android 6.0 wich worked perfectly). I've succesfully gained root acces on 7.0 and the recovery also works. The only thing that stopped working is my wifi after the TWRP and root (I did them at the same time so I don't know what caused it)

Thanks,
Niels

Comment: Try to catch the log while turning on Wi-Fi.

Comment: @Chahk When turning on wifi it displayes: "turning on..." with the turning on animation. But is keeps doing that.